# Who pays the gas when web.eth.sendSignedTransaction() called?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ethers.js, meta-transactions

I was trying meta transactions and i noticed in all examples only messages are signed and contract handles request manually using ecrecover. I wonder who pays the gas when web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction() or provider.sendTransaction() called?
I tried this and everytime i saw signer pays the gas :

Nodejs Server :

```
const contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
    let myData=contract.methods.setGreeting("From Backend").encodeABI()

    const txObject = {
         nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
         to: contractAddress,
         //value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether')),
         gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
         gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('100', 'gwei')),
         data : myData
    }
    // Sign the transaction
    const tx = new Tx(txObject);
    
    tx.sign(privateKey1)
    const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex');
res.json({raw});
```

Frontend gets the raw tx and calls like this:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:3001/message").then(async (res) => {
      
      // const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      // const { hash } = await provider.sendTransaction(
      //   res.data.raw
      // );
      // let a = await provider.waitForTransaction(hash);
     
       
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(res.data.raw, (err, txHash) => {
        console.log('txHash: ', txHash)
        console.log(err)
       })
      })
```

Whenever i call this, i see signer pays the gas. So if always signer pays the gas, then is this for only delayed operations? Should we use this for like sending anytime we want?

Comment: the signer. the signer can sign a transaction and give it to you and you or anyone can submit it to the network. "Should we use this for like sending anytime we want" ? not should but yes you could. However, it will not work if the signer already send a transaction and used that nonce

Comment: I see. Then there is no difference sending transaction directly and saving it to send later, as far as nonce remains same.

Comment: In some cases it can be helpful. If u have a contract that accept transactions only on Monday but you have access on your private key only on Sunday . In this case u can sign the transaction on Sunday and send it later on Monday. If you submit the transaction directly on Sunday it will be reverted , if u submit it on Monday it will go through.

Comment: Is there a real world example for this delayed tx approach? Are any of known dapps using this? Thanks for answers. It helped a lot !

Comment: Sadly idk if someone is using delayed tx approaches. But back to the method sendSingedTransaction, it is a very used method that call an RPC endpoint (probably eth_sendrawtransaction) and clients / libraries / you and me use it all the time to submit signed transactions to the node